# Compare values between vectors of unequal size to find values within a certain distance of each other (without loops?)

Tags: r

I have two vectors of unequal length full of numbers in R. I want to find all instances of vector 1 where the value is within 0.0015 of *any* value in vector 2, and then delete those instances out of vector 1. Is there a good way to do this without doing nested for loops? It's inefficient and is slowing my program down.

Currently I am iterating through the first vector and comparing each instance to every value from the second vector and I'm looking for an alternate approach. See below:

I have a vector called tracker, which by default is true, but will turn false if there is a value in the second vector that is closer than 0.0015 to the value of interest in the first vector. This tracker vector is my desired output, because as you can see at the bottom, I use it to filter a different vector.

```
tracker <- rep(TRUE,length = length(filteredMZunrounded))
for(i in 1:length(filteredMZunrounded)){
  for(j in 1:length(bg.unrounded)){
   if(abs(filteredMZunrounded[i]-bg.unrounded[j]) < 0.0015){
           tracker[i] <- FALSE
      }
  }
}

filteredMZ <- filteredMZ[tracker]
```

Comment: Please provide the code for at least a sample of your data and the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the inner loop :

```
tracker <- rep(TRUE,length = length(filteredMZunrounded))

for(i in 1:length(filteredMZunrounded)){
    if(any(abs(filteredMZunrounded[i]-bg.unrounded) < 0.0015)) {
      tracker[i] <- FALSE
    }
  }
}

filteredMZ <- filteredMZ[tracker]
```